# Why is my $scope.confirmPassword gets undefined after form submit?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI-Bootstrap widgets for AngularJS. One of my form variables is getting undefined when I submit my form.

Note: If I remove the tooltip directive then `$scope.confirmPassword` is fetched properly. I am new to AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap. Is this a bug in UI-Bootstrap?

Also, is it mandatory to define a `$scope.myform` variable in `MyAppCtrl`? If not defined along with tooltip directive does not work. After defining `$scope.myform={};` it works!

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myform.password" tooltip="Enter password" autocomplete="off" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-trigger="focus" placholder="Enter Password" /><br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="confirmPassword"  tooltip="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-trigger="focus" placholder="Confirm Password" /><br/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

function MyAppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myform = {};
    $scope.submit = function () {
        alert($scope.myform.password);
        alert($scope.confirmPassword);
    }
}
```

Please check the jsfiddle links

http://jsfiddle.net/fbL5K/6/ (This works!!)

http://jsfiddle.net/fbL5K/7/ (This does not!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in angular js. The tooltip and popover will create a new scope which makes the ng-model's scope to be lost.

Refer https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#my-input-elements-stop-working-when-i-place-a-tooltip--popover-on-it

Comment: This is not really a bug. Misko explains that is the way prototypical scope inheritance works.  But he does mention that someone logs a bug with Angular every week, so maybe he'll get sick of it and change it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the infamous "dot" ng-model issue. For ng-model to resolve properly, you should always have a "." in your ng-model.

[Working JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcsFL/2/)

You need `$scope.myform = {}` in your MyAppCtrl controller in order to create the myform model in your controller's scope.  This is important because you want your ng-model which is on your input child scope, to resolve to the same `$scope.myform` through $scope inheritance.

`$scope.confirmPassword` needs to change to `$scope.myform.confirmPassword` to ensure that the model resolves properly: using $scope inheritance, it will resolve 'myform' first, which it will find in your MyAppCtrl scope, and then resolve the 'confirmPassword' property on the model.  The important point is that they resolve to the same model.

Without a '.' in your ng-model, then as soon as you enter a value in the input text field, it will create a scope variable in your child scope that "shadows" the scope variable in your controller's scope, effectively breaking the two-way model binding.

There is a good explanation of the issue here:

[You should always have a "dot" in ng-model](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ngRepeat)

If you don't have a "dot" in ng-model, you're doing it wrong.  This is not strictly true, but good advice to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But, I dont want confirmPassword to be in myForm model. Do let me know if this wrong!!

Comment: You could create a different model rather than re-use myForm. For example, $scope.confirmPassword = { value: }; And then set your ng-model for your input field to ng-model="confirmPassword.value".

Comment: Yeah.. we could also use this. But, for this I need to define $scope.confirmPassword in my Ctrl. Anyhow thanks for the inputs.

I should choose b/w using $parent and $scope.confirmPassword = { value: }; 

Personally, I feel using $parent.confirmPassword which makes my  Controller shorter and clean.

Comment: Yes that will work. If you really want to bind to a primitive, using $parent.parentScopeProperty in child scope will prevent the child scope from creating its own property.